# Symmetric list with maximum in center

Tags: list-manipulation

How to sort a list, e.g.

```
RandomInteger[{0, 100}, 50]
```

that the Maximum is in the center and all other elements are placed symetrically in descending order around the center?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way:

```
SeedRandom[1];

#[[1 ;; ;; 2]] ~Join~ Reverse[#[[2 ;; ;; 2]]] &@
 Sort[RandomInteger[{0, 100}, 50]]
(*
  {0, 3, 4, 10, 15, 18, 24, 26, 29, 30, 38, 43, 44, 47, 54, 65, 68, 68, \
  70, 74, 76, 83, 86, 93, 100, 100, 97, 90, 86, 80, 75, 73, 69, 68, 67, \
  56, 48, 45, 44, 43, 33, 30, 28, 25, 23, 17, 14, 6, 4, 1}
*)
```

**Edit**: Or, following [@Mr.Wizard's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard) suggestion,

```
#[[1 ;; ;; 2]] ~Join~ #[[Floor[Length[#], 2] ;; 1 ;; -2]] &@
 Sort[RandomInteger[{0, 100}, 50]]
```

Comment: Both shorter *and* faster: `#[[;; ;; 2]] ~Join~ #[[-2 ;; 1 ;; -2]] &`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I guess I never thought about spanning backwards -- Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it's a nice trick for reversing, but I think I got the spec wrong the first time, now corrected.  Check it, will you?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Actually, as I started to edit, I think we have to worry whether the length of the list is odd or even.

Comment: You're right.  Hm....

Comment: @Mr.Wizard My first idea: `#[[1 ;; ;; 2]]~Join~#[[-1 - Boole@OddQ@Length[#] ;; 1 ;; -2]] &`

Comment: @MichaelE2 yes, having to worry about the length being odd or even makes things a lot uglier

Comment: Michael, after some concerted thought I came up with code I like better.  Please take a look.

Answer (score 2):

For practice we could write the same thing  as in Michael E2's answer with `Range` and `Extract`:

```
symSort[list_] := Module[
  {l = Length@list},
  Extract[Sort@list, List /@ Join @@ Range[{1, Floor[l, 2]}, {l, 1}, {2, -2}]]
  ]
```

Example:

```
SeedRandom[1];
symSort[RandomInteger[{0, 100}, 50]]

(* {0,3,4,10,15,18,24,26,29,30,38,43,44,47,54,65,68,68,
70,74,76,83,86,93,100,100,97,90,86,80,75,73,69,68,67,56,48,45,
44,43,33,30,28,25,23,17,14,6,4,1} *)
```

For lists with an even number of items we could also do

```
symSort[list_] := Join[First@#, Reverse@Last@#] &@Transpose@Partition[Sort@list, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Although this isn't *quite* as fast as Michael's revised method using negative stepping for reversal I find the following satisfyingly short and clean:

```
Join[#, Reverse @ #][[;; ;; 2]] &
```

Both methods are still very fast so I'd personally use this one. :-)

Comment: It takes a little thought to see that it is always correct, but it's quite clever and clean, as you say.  I believe it uses twice as much memory, but that's probably not much of a practical limitation. +1